# multiple different record types within same file must be converted to sql table

Tags: sql, types, row, record, multiple-records

One for the SQL data definition gurus:
I have a mainframe file that has about 35-100 different record types within it.  Depending upon the type of record the layout and each column is redefined into whatever.  Any column on any different record could become a different length or type.  I am not really wanting to split this thing up into 35-100 different tables and relating them together.  I did find out that postgres has %ROWTYPE with cursor or table based records.  However in all examples the data looked the same.  How can I setup a table that would handle this and what sql queries would be needed to return the data?  Doesn't have to be postgres but that was the only thing I could find, that looked similar to my problem.

Comment: You really should split up the data into a normalized structure. It will save you many more headaches in the future when you need to query the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would just make a table with all TEXT datatype fields at first. TEXT is variable, so it only takes up the space it needs, so it performs very well. From there, you may find it quicker to move the data into better formed tables, if certain data is better with a more specific data type.

It's easier to do it in this order, because bulk insert with COPY is very picky... so with TEXT you just worry about the number of columns and get it in there.

EDIT: I'm referring to Postgres with this answer. Not sure if you wanted another DB specific answer.